# Can't get an output from my c++ application

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ Express, and I'm wondering what's wrong with the following application, I can't get an output, it gives me an error. Since I'm not English, the error is in a different language, but it basically says something along the lines of 'The system can't find the given/stated path'.

I have literally checked it a dozen times but I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
 #include <iostream> 
using namespace std;


int DemoConsoleOutput ()
{
    cout << "This is a simple string literal" << endl;
    cout << "Writing number five:" << 5 << endl;
    cout << "Performing division 10/5 = " << 10 / 5 << endl;
    cout << "Pi when approximated is 22 / 7 = " << 22 / 7 << endl;
    cout << "Pi more accurately is 22 / 7 = " << 22.0 / 7 << endl;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    return DemoConsoleOutput ();
}
```

Can anyone help me find what's wrong with this?

**Addendum:** I also keep getting a weird error on my computer every couple minutes. It says: 'a program can't display a message on the desktop' and it gives me the options to show the message, or to give me another reminder in a few minutes. When I click 'show message' my screen goes black for a second and it then gives an error 'The application data folder for Microsoft visual c++ 2010 express could not be created'.

I don't know if it's important, but my OS is windows vista.

Comment: I suggest that the OS is telling you that it cannot run your program because the way in which you are attempting to run it does not in fact locate the executable. How are you attempting to run the program?

Comment: Have you built the executable? Are you running from the command line or from the IDE?

Comment: Are you sure everything is setup properly in VC++ ?
Make sure you're compiling correct file.
Else use http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php to see its output

Comment: @MikeKinghan All I did was just press Ctrl+F5 if that's what you mean. I'm very new to this all, not quite familair with the lingo yet

Comment: Then as Joachim Pileborg asks, did you actually *build* the program before your tried to run it?

Comment: @MikeKinghan I added an important addendum. If you mean what I think you mean, then yes, I did. I don't see how it would be possible to run it before building it, but I think the problem has been located, I just don't know what it means (see addendum)

Comment: @user14445 Your program builds and runs just as you'd expect for me. Sounds as if something is broken in your Visual Studio setup. Afraid I can't help your with that.

Comment: Run application in cmd and it will show standard output(stdout) of your application

Comment: The problem is when run like this (from visual studio or even from explorer) the console window will close immediately after the program finishes. So a program like this will flash a black window that will appear that nothing happened when in fact your program ran, finished and the window was closed. There are several ways around this.

Comment: @drescherjm But does this explain it saying 'the system cannot find the path specified'? The console window doesn't close, it gives me an the aforementioned error

Comment: Your application data error is (in my opinion) a bug in the installer for Visual Studio. I have seen that from time to time on working Visual Studio installs. Does the executable created for your project exist?

Comment: @drescherjm Don't know, I'm a rook. Would it solve the problem?

Comment: Open explorer to the location where your C++ project is located and look for an executable in the Debug folder.

Comment: As for the application data error. I would google for that. There are a few things to try to get around that.

Comment: Also when you compiled your project in the ide did the output indicate that the compile was successful?

Comment: @drescherjm the problem is that I don't get an output, it only gives me the error

Answer (score 1):

From the situation it seems that the application has insufficient rights to create a working folder and write an file in that folder. Possible causes can be that your anti virus is not letting VS do so or the folder has no write rights. Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327142/could-not-create-the-file-access-is-denied-and-unrecoverable-build-error) question.