# Unrecoverable build error - whilst trying to build setup on VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My build fails every time when I try and build my setup project.  The error in the output window is just:

**ERROR: Unrecoverable build error**

What I have tried already

- Restarting my computer and Visual Studio
- Registering ole32.dll
- Clean and rebuild all
- Deleting bin and obj folders
- Removing temporary files with VS in the name in \AppData\LocalTemp
- Running Visual Studio as an administrator
- Pausing the real time protection on my antivirus
- Deleting the temporary file that the setup build leaves in there.
- Running the process monitor during the build.
- Checking if my project contains duplicate folder names (it does not).

Note:
Similar question but not the same as it is for a much earlier version of Visual Studio:

- ["Unrecoverable build error" on any MSI Setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339106/unrecoverable-build-error-on-any-msi-setup-project)
- [“Could not create the file”, “Access is denied” and “Unrecoverable build error” in building setup project in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327142/could-not-create-the-file-access-is-denied-and-unrecoverable-build-error)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was solved by registering mergemod.dll.

On my computer it is located at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools

You need to run regsvr32 with administrative privileges to get it to work.

Comment: That did the trick for me too. This answer should get more visibility. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, but needed to run VS as admin afterwards to get past other errors (possibly unrelated)

Comment: I've just experienced this problem building a setup merge module using the latest VS 2019 16.7 preview 1. After registering mergemod.dll I had to close/restart VS before the problem was solved.

Comment: It work for me after 5 year, many thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had to do one additional step on top of the accepted answer:

1. Register the DLL mergemod.dll (regsvr32.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll)
2. Register the DLL ole32.dll (regsvr32.exe ole32.dll)
3. **Delete the cache/temporary visual studio files – which get generated as part of the builds. (C:\users{BUILD_USER}\appdata\local\temp).**

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall (Repair) Visual Studio resolved the problem for me. I've had installed a new software for creating setup programs and it damaged some setup msm files. The easiest mode to repair it was to reinstall VS.

Answer (score -1):

Running VS2017 in Admin mode solved my problem.